# QGraphicsPixmapItem doesn't show in QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qgraphicspixmapitem

In the inherited class GraphicWidgetItem from QGraphicsItem, I create rectangles, a circle, and a picture. Everything is displayed except the picture. What am I doing wrong?

```
CustomItem::CustomItem( QObject *parent):
   GraphicWidgetItem(parent)
{
    QGraphicsRectItem *topLevel = new QGraphicsRectItem(this);
    topLevel->setRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
    topLevel->setBrush(Qt::gray);
    topLevel->setPos(-30 , -30);

    QGraphicsRectItem *lowLevel = new QGraphicsRectItem(this);
    lowLevel->setRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
    lowLevel->setBrush(Qt::red);
    lowLevel->setPos(-30 , 60);

     QGraphicsEllipseItem *circle = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(this);
     circle->setBrush(Qt::green);
     circle->setRect(0, 0, 20, 20);

    QGraphicsPixmapItem* pi =  new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap(":/icons/image"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only 2 way for an item to appear in the scene:

- Add directly using addItem().
- Or be the children of an item that is already on the scene.

In your case "rectangles" and "circles" are shown because they are children of `CustomItem` but "pi" is not so it fails, the solution is to pass to "this" as parent:

```cpp
QGraphicsPixmapItem* pi =  new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap(":/icons/image"), this);
```

Or

```cpp
QGraphicsPixmapItem* pi =  new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap(":/icons/image"));
pi->setParent(this);
```